# MySQL Round Up to Nearest 5 Cents

Tags: mysql

I need to round up values using MySQL to increments of 5 cents (0.05). It has to ALWAYS round up. Examples:

0.01 -> 0.05

2.12 -> 2.15

0.16 -> 0.20

How can I accomplish this. I tried a few things with ceil() and round(), but it seems like I can use some help from a MySQL expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this one -

```
SELECT (<value> DIV 0.05) * 0.05 + IF(<value> MOD 0.05 = 0, 0, 0.05)
```

Comment: Nope. 0.10 is rounding to 0.15.

Comment: :) I like your change. Does it have to be that complicated?

Comment: Working now. I will use it if I don't get a shorter answer. I don't want to look back at the code later and say what the heck I did here? :) I understand what you're doing though.

Comment: The second part complicates the query. But it needed to round UP values.

Answer (score 7):

Since 100/5 = 20 all we do is multiply by 20, round up to the nearest whole number, and then divide by 20.

(To round up in MySQL use CEIL)

Example for $1.03:

```
1.03 * 20   = 20.60
CEIL(20.60) = 21.0000
21 / 20     = 1.0500
```

NOTE: I also round the whole statement to 2 decimals places just to remove any trailing zeros.

```
SELECT ROUND( CEIL( (old_price) * 20) / 20, 2) FROM table
```

EDIT: A generalized example (notice the 100.00 to cast the value as non-integer)

```
SELECT ROUND( CEIL ( (old_price) * (100.00/the_increment)) / (100.00/the_increment), 2) FROM table
```

Comment: elegant solution, easy to adjust for any value

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT floor((<value> + 0.025) * 20) / 20
```

Comment: Can you give a little more explanation? In general, code-only answers are frowned upon as they are very specific and often hard to understand later.

Comment: @WesleyBland Just do the math.

Comment: @user3357191 downvote for not giving an explanation.

Comment: I did not see your comment.

Comment: It is an old trick from assembler.
It is hard to explain. Take a piece of paper an calculate it, and you will understand.
We used it in the beginning of programming for rounding to 2 decimals with floor( ( x + 0.05) * 100) / 100.
To floor was easy by converting a float to an integer.