# SQL money round to closest 0.05 cents

Tags: mysql, math, rounding

I'm trying to round money in MySQL SELECT to the closest 0.05 cents.

so numbers like:

```
140.70  should become 140.70
140.71  should become 140.70
140.72  should become 140.70
140.73  should become 140.75
140.74  should become 140.75
140.75  should become 140.75
140.76  should become 140.75
140.77  should become 140.75
140.78  should become 140.80
140.79  should become 140.80
```

So more in detail

```
0.00 = 0.00
0.01 = 0.00
0.02 = 0.00
0.022 = 0.00   // here the magic should happen 0.022 is closer to 0, so result is 0
0.023 = 0.05   // but 0.023 should be rounded to 0.05! cause first round 0.023 to 0.025 which should then be rounded up to 0.05
0.03 = 0.05
```

I've tried some different things with [MySQL CEIL()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceil) and [MySQL FLOOR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor) but couldn't get the right result.

Created a [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c28a0f/1/0)

With a table which makes no sense, except we need one to SELECT from:

```
CREATE TABLE hello ( world varchar(255) );
INSERT INTO hello (world) VALUES ('blubb');
```

This is the select Query:

```
SELECT 

 CEILING ( 0.05 / 0.05 ) * 0.05 AS CEIL_1,
 CEILING ( 0.06 / 0.05 ) * 0.05 AS CEIL_2,
 CEILING ( 0.07 / 0.05 ) * 0.05 AS CEIL_3,
 CEILING ( 0.08 / 0.05 ) * 0.05 AS CEIL_4,
 CEILING ( 0.09 / 0.05 ) * 0.05 AS CEIL_5

FROM hello;
```

Anyone here telling me how to do it right?

Comment: Your sample data suggests that you want `ROUND()` rather than `CIELING()`.  Does that fix your problem?

Comment: @GordonLinoff that helps a little, but how to round to `0.05` ?

Comment: this post might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081897/mysql-round-up-to-nearest-5-cents

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT ROUND(140.77/5,2) * 5;
+-----------------------+
| ROUND(140.77/5,2) * 5 |
+-----------------------+
|                140.75 |
+-----------------------+
```